# How to remove '/5' from CSV file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am cleaning a restaurant data set using Pandas' `read_csv`.

I have columns like this:

```
name, online_order, book_table, rate, votes
xxxx, Yes, Yes, 4.5/5, 705
```

I expect them to be like this:

```
name, online_order, book_table, rate, votes
xxxx, Yes, Yes, 4.5, 705
```

Comment: Yeah, this is not the only row, and I'm sure '/5' isn't the only kind of junk you'll find in your DataFrame. Please provide a more concrete sample with more rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python `.split()` function to remove specific text, given that the text is consistently going to be "/5", and there are no instances of "/5" that you want to keep in that string. You can use it like this:

```
num = "4.5/5"
num.split("/5")[0]

output: '4.5'
```

If this isn't exactly what you need, there's more regex python functions [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/WhirlwindTourOfPython/14-strings-and-regular-expressions.html)

Comment: `.strip` is problematic. You should see what happens when you try to strip `'/5'` from the string `'4.5/5'`, it's a common pitfall :(.

Comment: This is not a pandas answer.

Comment: Thanks ALollz, just edited to use a working fix. This will work regardless of whether OP is using pandas or not

Comment: `using Pandas'`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DataFrame.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to make your replacement operation on the `rate`column:

```
def clean(x):
    if "/" not in x :
       return x
    else:
       return x[0:x.index('/')]

df.rate = df.rate.apply(lambda x : clean(x))
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
+----+-------+---------------+-------------+-------+-------+
|    | name  | online_order  | book_table  | rate  | votes |
+----+-------+---------------+-------------+-------+-------+
| 0  | xxxx  | Yes           | Yes         |  4.5  |   705 |
+----+-------+---------------+-------------+-------+-------+
```

**EDIT**

Edited to handle situations in which there could be multiple `/` or that it could be another number than `/5` (ie : `/4`or `/1/3` ...)

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to split the item(`dataframe["rate"]`) based on `/` and take out what you need. `.apply` this on your dataframe using `lambda x: getRate(x)`

```
def getRate(x):
    return str(x).split("/")[0]
```

To use it with column name `rate`, we can use:

`dataframe["rate"] = dataframe["rate"].apply(lambda x: getRate(x))`

Comment: This is too general in this case, what if there are other strings with an `/` in them?

Comment: Won't work for '1/2/5` (where only /5 is to be removed as per OP's reqs)

Comment: @Erfan, edited my post. What I meant was to use getRate with only the column that needs it, i.e, "rate" here.

Comment: @cs95, what I understood from OP's dataset is, it's a rating of a book where one can feed a positive integer or a float that is < 5.